# Energy required to keep an object in circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

I know that no work is done to keep an object in a circular path because the tangential velocity is not changing, but I am wondering how to find the energy required to keep an object moving in that circular path.

If a $1\ \rm kg$ object is spinning around a pole, for example, and it's $1\ \rm m$ off the ground, and moving with a tangential velocity of, say, $2\ \rm m/s$, is the energy just:

$$\begin{align}
U_{\text{total}}&= KE + U_g\\
&= .5\times m\times v^2 + mgh\\
&= .5\times1\times4 + 1\times10\times1\\
&= 12\ \rm J
\end{align}$$

I just picked arbitrary numbers here, whether or not it's actually moving fast enough to stay that high off the ground I don't know.

Comment: start using latex markup by enclosing equations between $. http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

It's a slightly curious question. If an object is moving in a circular path then no more energy is required, it already has the necessary energy. 
If there are losses, such as air resistance or friction, this energy needs to be put back in somehow.

Comment: That makes sense. In retrospect, I'm not even sure what I wanted to know, perhaps I was trying to think of it in terms of a motor powering the motion or something.

Comment: The fact that the object has gravity acting on it as well doesn't change anything does it? It would just be equal to the y component of the tension force, correct?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Work required is energy required.

There's an energy required to get that system into motion; and that will have to do with the kinetic energy.

Once it's in motion if we assume no friction losses than there is no more work required.

You can find the total energy of the system, and that should be the same as the work required to make the system.

Answer (score 0):

A body in circular motion has centripetal force in the radial direction $\vec F~=m\omega\vec r$. The displacement of the body is in the tangential direction $d\vec x~=~rd\vec\theta$ that is perpendicular to the radial direction. Hence the incremental work required to keep something on a circular path through the angle $d\theta$ is $dW~=~\vec F\cdot d\vec x$ and the perpendicularity of the radius and the displacement means $dW = 0$ and the total work $W~=~\int dW$ is zero. Hence there is no energy expenditure in a body that maintains a constant circular motion.

A body in circular motion does have a constant net energy $E~=~\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$, for $\omega$ the angular velocity and $I$ the moment of inertial. This is constant for a body in constant circular motion.